# I am getting shape related error on running the fit function

Tags: python, shapes, conv-neural-network

valueError: A target array with shape (90, 300, 300, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 1) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

I am getting the above error when I run the below code. Can anyone please help me to rectify it.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import pickle
import numpy as np

# X = np.array(pickle.load(open("X.pickle","rb")))
# Y = np.array(pickle.load(open("Y.pickle","rb")))

X = np.array(pickle.load(open("x_train.pickle","rb")))
Y = np.array(pickle.load(open("y_train.pickle","rb")))

#scaling our image data
X = X/255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64 ,(3,3), input_shape = X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512 ,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(2048))
model.add(Activation("relu"))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
             optimizer = "adam",
             metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()
model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=32, epochs = 1, validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of the images?

Comment: Both X and Y are of (90,300,300,1) shape.

Comment: The output of your model has shape (90, 1). The shape of Y is (90, 300, 300, 1). You cannot compute a loss between these shapes.

Comment: Then how should I change it .

Comment: Y should be the labels of the images, 0 being the first class you want to classify (e.g. "cat"), 1 being the second class (e.g. "dog")

Comment: X was the feature set and Y was the label, but in order to split the data into train and test set, I used model.train_test_split(X,Y) and now I have used this y_train for the fit function. If I use Y instead of y_train then this fit function works well. But to get confusion matrix then.